# How do i get root project directory of Intellij during runtime execution

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to code out an import function that imports certain content of file into intellij. I would like to specify the default path of this file as one of the directories under my content root. I would want to know if intellij provides a specific function call to get the content root during runtime? 
Since i will not be able to hardcode the file path as they differ for different computers.

For example under my content root directory called "main", I have a "data" folder which i want to use as my directory for importing files inside that folder.

Comment: Why not just use the default working directory path and the path relative to it?

Comment: but if other users import the project into their computers, they might have a different working directory for it ? What i had in mind was for a method call that allows user to retrieve their content-root directory path so they can import the file stored under another folder in another directory under the content-root.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA stores all the paths inside run configurations relatively to the project root so that the project can run on any machine out of the box.

Comment: how would i get the project root in intellij ?

Comment: [Working directory](https://i.imgur.com/XexIL9I.png) is set to the project root automatically. You can use `File directory = new File("./data").getCanonicalPath();` in your code to get the full path to the `data` directory on any system where the project will be running.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! it helped :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA run configuration **working directory** defaults to the project root. Even if you change it, its path will be stored relatively in the project so that it can work on any system.

Sample code to get the path of the `data` directory that resides under the current working directory:

```
package com.jetbrains.support;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File directory = new File("./data");
    System.out.println(directory.getCanonicalPath());
  }
}
```

To get the working directory (project root) path without the `data` subdirectory you can use this code:

```
File directory = new File("./").getCanonicalPath();
```

Proof of work:

[image: proof]